# Integrate Linter(JSLint\ESLint) to Google V8 Script compilation

Tags: c++, eslint, v8, jslint

I wrote an application that using Google V8 engine. 
And I want to introduce printing warning messages in script compilation output. 
There is no problem to load linter .js file, compile it and run `lint(my_script)` function. 
The problem is that I use objects and functions in my script that I add by V8 like this:

```
global->Set(isolate_, "my_func", v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate_, V8Context::MyFunc, data));
```

And ofcourse when I call linter it say: `"Undeclared 'my_func'"`.

Is there way to prevent this type of errors?
Or maybe there is another way to 'check script for warnings'?

Comment: What linter are you using specifically?

Comment: I was try with JSLint, because it is the easiest one to integrate